# Como fazer mais de um campo type="radio" sem outro perder o valor?

Tags: jquery, jquery.validate

Pessoal estou fazendo um formulário e ele vai ter dois campos para seleção de itens, ou seja eles são type="radio", só que acontece o seguinte problema quando ele seleciona uma alternativa da primeira questão ta certo, mas quando ele seleciona a segunda a primeira desmarca, vou enviar meu codigo e vocês me ajudem é coisa simples só que não estou conseguindo.

```html
<div>
    <div class="col-md-12">                                      
        <label for="gender">
            Melhor forma para contato:
        </label>
    </div>                                
    <div class="col-md-push-2 col-md-6 padding-botton">
        <label for="tfixo">
            <input id="tfixo" type="radio" name="gender" value="t-fixo"> 
            Tel. Fixo
        </label><br>
        <label for="tcel">
            <input id="tcel" type="radio" name="gender" value="t-cel"> 
            Tel. Celular
        </label><br>
        <label for="emaill">
            <input id="emaill" type="radio" name="gender" value="email"> 
            E-mail
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label>
            Melhor horário para contato:
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-push-2 col-md-6 padding-botton">
        <label for="manha">
            <input id="manha" type="radio" name="gender" value="manha"> 
            Manhã
        </label><br>
        <label for="tarde">
            <input id="tarde" type="radio" name="gender" value="tarde"> 
            Tarde
        </label><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oi! Se alguma das respostas em baixo resolveu o teu problema, então podes [marcar ela como aceite](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/129).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não pode usar igual o tipo de campo gender de outro, precisa separar, veja mudei para periodo, o valor não erra.

```html
<div>
    <div class="col-md-12">                                      
        <label for="gender">
            Melhor forma para contato:
        </label>
    </div>                                
    <div class="col-md-push-2 col-md-6 padding-botton">
        <label for="tfixo">
            <input id="tfixo" type="radio" name="gender" value="t-fixo"> 
            Tel. Fixo
        </label><br>
        <label for="tcel">
            <input id="tcel" type="radio" name="gender" value="t-cel"> 
            Tel. Celular
        </label><br>
        <label for="emaill">
            <input id="emaill" type="radio" name="gender" value="email"> 
            E-mail
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label>
            Melhor horário para contato:
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-push-2 col-md-6 padding-botton">
        <label for="manha">
            <input id="manha" type="radio" name="periodo" value="manha"> 
            Manhã
        </label><br>
        <label for="tarde">
            <input id="tarde" type="radio" name="periodo" value="tarde"> 
            Tarde
        </label><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Estás a dar o mesmo `name="gender"` aos dois. Esse `name` tem de ser único para cada grupo.

O `name` é a maneira como o browser sabe que esses inputs pertencem ao mesmo grupo, ou seja que só um deles pode ser escolhido de cada vez.

Assim tens de mudar o `name` do segundo grupo para por exemplo `timeofday` para os inputs que escolhem manhã/tarde:

```
<div class="col-md-push-2 col-md-6 padding-botton">
    <label for="manha">
        <input id="manha" type="radio" name="timeofday" value="manha"> 
        Manhã
    </label><br>
    <label for="tarde">
        <input id="tarde" type="radio" name="timeofday" value="tarde"> 
        Tarde
    </label><br>
</div>
```